# populate backend create form

Tags: octobercms

With the builder tool i created a standart backend form for my Customer model.

When I display the related create page (with url like .../myadmin/author/myplugin/customers/create), in some case, I need to be able to populate some text fields with predefined values (from an oldCustomer model precisely)

I tried a system D tech by forcing a value in my session or in my input but that does not work

my try with session

```
Session::flash('email', 'foo@bar.com');
return Redirect::to('/myadmin/author/myplugin/customers/create');
```

or with input option

```
Input::flashOnly('email', 'foo@bar.com');
return Redirect::to('/myadmin/author/myplugin/customers/create')->withInput();
```

which gives the following result in my session debugbar tab

```
_old_input  array:2 [ "email" => null "foo@bar" => array:1 [ "com" => null ] ]
```

here we can see email is set but with null value then after this is whatever.

i feel i'm not so far but already spending half a day on it !
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default values in the model constructor.

Check the session for the old value and if it exists, populate the required fields with the data.